File Upload in Swagger
I have an endpoint in swagger UI where I upload a .txt file and looks like this:
[HttpPost("UploadBlackList")]
public IActionResult UploadBlackList(IFormFile formFile)
{
  try
  {
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      using Proceso proceso = new Proceso(_log, _datos, _storage, _gdp, _client, _apiIag, _proxy);
      await proceso.UploadBlackList(formFile);
    });
    return Accepted();
  }
  catch (Exception err)
  {
    _log.LogError(err.Message);
    return BadRequest();
  }
}

After that is there the function:
await proceso.UploadBlackList(formFile);

Here I have the processing part of the file but when I try to read the file:
 public async Task UploadBlackList(IFormFile formFile)
 {
   using var tabla = new Tabla(_log, _storage);

   var lines = new List<string>();
   try
   {
     using (var stream = formFile.OpenReadStream())
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
     {
       while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
       {
         var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
         var sinleer = new SinLeer
         {
           PartitionKey = _partitionKey,
           RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
           Estado = line
         };
       }
     }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     _log.LogError($"Internal server error: {ex.Message}");
   }
 }


Here when I call the OpenReadStream() I get this error:
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.String'.'

What am I doing wrong here ?
I tried to run with .copytoasync but is the same problem as in this case.

Can you share the stack trace showing where the exception is coming from? A string being disposed doesn't really make any sense.

My guess would be that IFormFile is gone after return Accepted(); The Task try's to use  it afterwards.
